# How to recover Java file from Eclipse Project that damaged by getting power off?

Tags: eclipse

it happens with me that, I am working on a project with Eclipse. And Suddenly power gone.
And after some times while power come back and i open the project in eclipse, i found my all code gone. and see the Screen with error like below image:

[image]

So Please what wrong with that Eclipse ? How to recove that java file from eclipse.
If i go to that file localy and open that file it open in Word with many pages. but with no text.

Comment: May be the data got lost on physical level, e.g. by the used HDD/SSD?

Comment: @Robert: So how to get it ? Please help me. I realy need it.

Comment: @Robert : Please help me if you have any idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try the eclipse's local history..
right click the file -->replace with-->previous from Local History.

Comment: what it will do ? I want my all last save code so will it will be back ?

Comment: i have just work before an hour a lot. And suddenly because of power off, i lot that code. i havent save that data. So please help me to recove that code.

Comment: Eclipse's local histry means the place where i am saving all the project, right ???

Comment: Thanks i got that file. But there are some code remaining in it. But still it save my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in Eclipse editor -> right click -> Team -> Show Local History“
View the result in ‘History View’ and chose the last best state of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ,and also you can try for some method restore,Right Click in editor->Local History->Replace with.. 
THis will help to get back the previous changes u made...

Answer (score 0):

Get the previous file back from the cache with help of eclipse's local history. 
Right click on the damaged file -->Replace with-->Previous from Local History.